# How to format a calendar in java based on user input

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I have to ask a user for a month, year, and the day that month starts and print out a calendar of that specific month, in that specific year. My code works perfectly other than the fact that the column for Sunday is completely blank.

I've tried including selection statements to determine where the spacing should be for each column, but it still ends up with the week practically being 6 days, instead of 7.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthCalendar {
   // method for determining # of days
   public static int numOfDays(int month, int year) {
      int numDays = 0;
      switch (month) {
      case 1:
      case 3:
      case 5:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 10:
      case 12:
         numDays = 31;
         break;
      case 4:
      case 6:
      case 9:
      case 11:
         numDays = 30;
         break;
      case 2:
         if (isLeap(year))
            numDays = 29;
         else
            numDays = 28;
         break;
      }
      return numDays;
   }

   // determine if leap year
   public static Boolean isLeap(int year) {
      if (((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }

   // get month name from user int
   public static String getMonthName(int month) {
      String monthName = "j";
      switch (month) {
      case 1:
         monthName = "January";
         break;
      case 2:
         monthName = "February";
         break;
      case 3:
         monthName = "March";
      break;
      case 4:
         monthName = "April";
         break;
      case 5:
         monthName = "May";
         break;
      case 6:
         monthName = "June";
         break;
      case 7:
         monthName = "July";
         break;
      case 8:
         monthName = "August";
         break;
      case 9:
         monthName = "September";
         break;
      case 10:
         monthName = "October";
         break;
      case 11:
         monthName = "November";
         break;
      case 12:
         monthName = "December";
         break;
      }
      return monthName;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //prompt user for month, year, and day
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter month (number), year, and day of the first date (number): ");
      System.out.println();
      int month = input.nextInt();
      int year = input.nextInt();
      int day = input.nextInt();
      int numDays = numOfDays(month, year);

      // print heading
      System.out.println("\t\t" + getMonthName(month) + " " + year);
      System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");

      // determine starting day of the week
      day %= 7;
      for (int b = 0; b <= day * 7; b++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }

      // print calendar
      for (int d = 1; d <= numOfDays(month, year); d++) {
         // format for single digits to line up with the first digit of two digit #'s'
         if (d < 10) {
              System.out.print(" ");
         }
         // go to next line if at end of week
         if (day % 6 == 0) {
             System.out.print("\t" + d + "\n");
         }
         // normal formatting for other days
         else {
             System.out.print("\t" + d);
         }   
         day++;
      }

   }
}
```

The output that's needed (for, example, September 2017) is

```
                      September 2017
    ---------------------------------------------------
     Sun    Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri    Sat
                                        1      2
     3      4      5      6      7      8      9
     10     11     12     13     14     15     16
     17     18     19     20     21     22     23
     24     25     26     27     28     29     30
```

But what I get with my code is

```
                      September 2017
    ---------------------------------------------------
     Sun    Mon    Tue    Wed    Thu    Fri    Sat
                                        1      2
            3      4      5      6      7      8
            9      10     11     12     13     14
            15     16     17     18     19     20
            21     22     23     24     25     26
            27     28     29     30
```

Comment: Is it just that: if (day%6 == 0) should be: if(day%7 == 0) ?

Comment: and if it is a Sunday you do not want a `tab`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use condition: `if(day%7 == 0)` because week has 7 days right?
and you have to do formatting with `\t` like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MonthCalendar {
   // method for determining # of days
   public static int numOfDays(int month, int year) {
      int numDays = 0;
      switch (month) {
      case 1:
      case 3:
      case 5:
      case 7:
      case 8:
      case 10:
      case 12:
         numDays = 31;
         break;
      case 4:
      case 6:
      case 9:
      case 11:
         numDays = 30;
         break;
      case 2:
         if (isLeap(year))
            numDays = 29;
         else
            numDays = 28;
            break;
      }
      return numDays;
   }

   // determine if leap year
   public static Boolean isLeap(int year) {
      if (((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }

   // get month name from user int
   public static String getMonthName(int month) {
      String monthName = "j";
      switch (month) {
         case 1:
         monthName = "January";
         break;
         case 2:
         monthName = "February";
         break;
         case 3:
         monthName = "March";
         break;
         case 4:
         monthName = "April";
         break;
         case 5:
         monthName = "May";
         break;
         case 6:
         monthName = "June";
         break;
         case 7:
         monthName = "July";
         break;
         case 8:
         monthName = "August";
         break;
         case 9:
         monthName = "September";
         break;
         case 10:
         monthName = "October";
         break;
         case 11:
         monthName = "November";
         break;
         case 12:
         monthName = "December";
         break;
      }
      return monthName;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //prompt user for month, year, and day
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter month (number), year, and day of the first date (number): ");
      System.out.println();
      int month = input.nextInt();
      int year = input.nextInt();
      int day = input.nextInt();
      int numDays = numOfDays(month, year);

      // print heading
      System.out.println("\t\t\t" + getMonthName(month) + " " + year);
      System.out.println("\t---------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println("\tSun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat");

      // determine starting day of the week
      day %= 7;
      for (int b = 0; b <= day * 7; b++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }

      // print calendar
      for (int d = 1; d <= numOfDays(month, year); d++) {
         // format for single digits to line up with the first digit of two digit #'s'
         if (d < 10) {
              System.out.print(" ");
         }
         // go to next line if at end of week
         if (day % 7 == 0) {
             System.out.print("\t" + d + "\n");
         }
         // normal formatting for other days
         else {
             System.out.print("\t" + d);
         }   
         day++;
      }

   } 
}
```